# Measurable functions are not polynomials

Tags: measure-theory

The problem I have says:

> If $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb R$, prove that there is at most a countable number of polynomials $P$ such that $P\overset{\text{a.e.}}{=}f$.

I think I need to show that if $f$ is not a polynomial then it is different almost everywhere from every polynomial. I don't know how to show this though, if it is correct.

Now, if $f$ is a polynomial, then if $f\overset{\text{a.e.}}{=}P_1$ and $f\overset{\text{a.e.}}{=} P_2$, then that means that $P_1\overset{\text{a.e.}}{=}P_2$ where $P_1,P_2$ are polynomials, but doesn't that mean that $P_1=P_2$? I have a hard time finding a counter-example to this. That is where I don't understand the at most countable part, it seems to me that if a function is almost everywhere equal to a polynomial, then it can't be almost everywhere equal to another one.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I presume you are using Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Tom Yes, that is correct!

Comment: I think your remark is spot on then. A common exercise in this game is that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, then $f \stackrel{a.e.}{=} g$ if and only if $f = g$. Certainly polynomials are continuous, and certainly $\stackrel{a.e.}{=}$ is transitive. Therefore your conclusion that at most only one polynomial can equal a measurable function a.e. is correct.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for your help, I see now! It was simple indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to see that "if two polynomials $P_1$ and $P_2$ are equal almost everywhere, then they are identically equal" is to note that the hypothesis is equivalent to $P_1 - P_2$ equaling $0$ almost everywhere. But $P_1 - P_2$ is still a polynomial, so it either has finitely many roots (impossible in this case) or else is identically zero.

Answer (score 0):

Since the unique open set with $0$ measure is the empty set, the set where two continuous functions are different is either empty or of positive measure.

So given a measurable function $f$, there is at most one continuous function $g$ such that $f=g$ almost everywhere. (if $g_1$ and $g_2$ do the job, $g_1=g_2$ almost everywhere, hence (by continuity) everywhere.

Comment: The set of inputs for which two continuous functions have the same value is a closed set, not an open set. It is definitely possible for two different continuous functions to agree on, say, a Cantor set.

Comment: Yes, I meant the set where the two functions are _different_. I've edited. I made it CW as it is based on @Tom's comment.